# Extra spaces and text using a custom editor in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, editor

Basically, im trying to make a custom player controller inspector editor.

Everything works fine however whenever i use a foldout theres an extra space and duplicate bold text. as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aarFb.png)
(if you cant tell it adds movement settings again in bold after a space)

When adding a label it works fine with no gaps. seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDLhq.png)

Can someone tell me why its adding this extra text and space?
here is the code for referance (also for anyone whos going to comment on all the commented variables, theyre only temporary and ill sort them out later):

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
[CustomEditor(typeof(PlayerController))]
class PlayerControllerEditor : Editor {
    static bool isMovementDropDown = false;
    //public float moveSpeed = 8f;
    //public float maxFallSpeed = 20f;

    static bool isJumpDropDown = false;
    //public float jumpForce = 6f;
    //public float maxJumpTime = 0.3f;
    //public int jumpCount = 2;
    //public float coyoteTime = 10f;
    //public Vector2 groundCheckScale;
    //public Transform groundCheckPosition;
    //public LayerMask groundLayer;

    static bool isDashDropDown = false;
    //public float dashForce = 10f;
    //public float dashTime = 0.2f;
    //public float dashCooldown = 3f;
    //public bool dashOnGround = false;

    static bool isAttackDropDown = false;
    //public float attackCooldown = 0.5f;
    //public Transform attackUpCheck, attackSideCheck, attackDownCheck;
    //public GameObject slashPrefab;

    static bool isSSDropDown = false;
    //public float stretch = 0.1f;
    //public Transform sprite;

    static bool isEffectsDropDown = false;
    //public ParticleSystem skidParticle;
    //public ParticleSystem dashPuffParticle;
    // ENABLED/DISABLED ITEMS
    private SerializedProperty _movementSpeed;
    private void OnEnable() {
        _movementSpeed = serializedObject.FindProperty("moveSpeed");
    }
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        var playerController = (PlayerController)target;
        if (playerController == null) return;

        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Player Controller", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
        isMovementDropDown = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(isMovementDropDown, "Movement Settings", true);
        if (isMovementDropDown) {
            EditorGUI.indentLevel += 1;
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("hello");
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_movementSpeed);
            EditorGUI.indentLevel -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_movementSpeed);
```

by default will include a label + any additional drawer attributes used on the field, in this case might e.g. be the `[Header]` attribute (don't know the implementation details of `PlayerController`)

You can skip it using

```
EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_movementSpeed, GUIContent.None);
```

But then the field will have no label at all. So additionally you can prefix the default one again like e.g.

```
EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel(_movementSpeed.displayName);
EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_movementSpeed, GUIContent.None);
```

Or maybe also directly via

```
EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_movementSpeed, new GUIContent(_movementSpeed.displayName));
```

---

Just fyi for further complex types you should also pass in the second optional parameter

```
boop includeChildren
```

otherwise you might end up with a field that is basically only the topmost reference but missing properties

> If true the property including children is drawn; otherwise only the control itself (such as only a foldout but nothing below it).

Comment: I see, thankyou! Yeah, after some debugging i found the issue was with the PropertyField, instead i just used a FloatField which fixed the issue: _movementSpeed = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("Movement Speed:", _movementSpeed, GUILayout.MinWidth(50));